# iTextSharp IOException "Trailer not found"

Tags: c#, .net, itext

am using iTextSharp ( .NET 2.0 Vista ). The iTextSharp Version is 4.1.2.0

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
```

is causing the library to thrown an exception saying
"Trailer not found"
  The file exists and can be viewed in Adobe no problem
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: I am having this exact same issue.  I tried upgrading itextsharp to version 5.0.0, but it still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The trailer is a part the structure of a PDF file.  If you're getting an error saying it can't be found then the first thing I'd think is your file is corrupt.  Being able to open the PDF in a PDF viewer program doesn't necessarily mean the PDF isn't corrupt; I understand that if it's a linearized PDF file the viewer won't attempt to use the trailer.

Does your code throw an IOException for any PDF you attempt to read?

- If so, then maybe using a more recent
  version of iTextSharp will help or at least post some code.
- If not, then I'd work on recreating
  the PDFs you're trying to process.

Comment: we dont control the PDF or rather where it comes in from . typically we process PDF that come in as attachments on an email so ...
the code works fine for about 95% of the PDF's we have tested on and also I have tried this with the latest libraries
So what did you mean by re-create?
Thanks

Comment: I was hoping you did control the creation of your PDFs and could do so and prevent the error.  I suppose the only thing I can suggest is to repair the PDFs you get the error on.  If you Google 'PDF repair' a number of hits are returned but since I've never had to do this I can't make any specific recommendations.  Sorry.

Comment: After doing some testing, I found that the issue I had related to a corrupt PDF.  As soon as I ran an pdf repair, the file worked correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: How to you repair your PDF? I've run into this problem today!

Comment: This tool does the job: https://www.ilovepdf.com/repair-pdf